Пропорциональность высот блоков на сайте и макете в резиновой верстке
А правильно ли я понимаю, что для резиновой верстки не только ширина блоков на сайте и макете должны быть пропорциональны, но и высоты блоков?
Если да, то как достичь пропорциональности высот блоков при резиновой верстки, ведь общая высота страницы сайта при верстке неизвестна.

Слишком абстрактно. Можно пример?
